# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.js:17), why is it happening?

Tags: javascript, html

I was doing a counter project and had this issue a couple of times but I couldn't find what the issue was so I copy and pasted the js from a counter project that free code camp did and that won't work.  What am I missing?  Also, any best practice tips and general advice is appreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <title>Counter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="counterContainer">
        <h1>Counter</h1>
        <br>
        <div class="counter" id="counter">
          54
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonContainer">
        <button type="button" class="decreaseButton button" id="decreaseButton">
          Decrease
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="resetButton button" id="resetButton">
          Reset
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="increaseButton button" id="increaseButton">
          increase
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

js

```
// set inital value to zero
let count = 0;
// select value and buttons
const value = document.querySelector("counter");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");

btns.forEach(function (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const styles = e.currentTarget.classList;
    if (styles.contains("decreaseButton")) {
      count--;
    } else if (styles.contains("increaseButton")) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count = 0;
    }
    value.textContent = count;
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to add the class/id selector in the element, I'm pretty sure. Try `const value = document.querySelector("#counter");`

Comment: Apart from above, you should be able to trap the error by checking if `styles` contains the value you want the code look for. An easy way is to place ` const styles = e.currentTarget.classList;` below the statement `const styles = e.currentTarget.classList;`.  I am only trying to tell how to debug.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, mistake is here `const value = document.querySelector("counter");`
This selector selects non-existent HTML element `counter`. Should select by class or id, like `const value = document.querySelector(".counter");` or `const value = document.querySelector("#counter");`. Both valid for this example, but for unique element id is preferred.

Regarding general advice, this code is out of sync since start - shows 54, but the real value of counter is 0. Avoid that. You can set initial text in counter element from the actual value or vice versa - set counter value from the text value on page init.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers/advice you guys are amazing and awesome.  What is the drawback for having the values out of sync?  I could guess a few reasons I’m just curious and want to know

Comment: Values out of sync are just misleading and result in bugs and/or wrong actions taken by user based on what he/she sees. If money involved you can easily end up in court under fraud charge.